# what happens when a function returns null?

Tags: javascript, null

In this js code, a number is produced by starting from 1 and repeatedly adding 5 or multiplying by 3.

What happens when the function 'find' returns null and how the machine finds the solution that match the number 24

```js
function findSolution(target) {
    function find (current, history) {
        if (current == target) {
            return history;
        } else if (current > target) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`) || find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);
        }
    }
    return find(1, '1');
}

console.log(findSolution(24));
```

Comment: `null || <any value>` = `<any value>`

Comment: `falsy || <any value>` = `<any value>` - the number 0 is falsy too

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet to understanding this code is to do two things:

1. Modify the code slightly to make it easier to step through with the debugger. (There's nothing *wrong* with the code as-is, it's just not set up for debugging by a beginner.)
2. Use the debugger built into your IDE and/or browser to step through the code statement by statement, watching the values of variables and such.

Here's the change I'd make to the code to make it easier to understand with a debugger for a beginner:

```js
function findSolution(target) {
    function find (current, history) {
        if (current == target) {
            return history;
        } else if (current > target) {
            return null;
        } else {
            const plusFive = find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`);
            if (plusFive) { // if `plusFive` is truthy
                return plusFive;
            } else {        // `plusFive` was falsy (probably `null`, could be `0`)
                const timesThree = find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);
                return timesThree;
            }
        }
    }
    return find(1, '1');
}

console.log(findSolution(24));
```

You can see I've replaced the line

```
return find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`) || find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);
```

with this `if`/`else` block for each side of the `||`:

```
const plusFive = find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`);
if (plusFive) { // if `plusFive` is truthy
    return plusFive;
} else {        // `plusFive` was falsy (probably `null`, could be `0`)
    const timesThree = find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);
    return timesThree;
}
```

That makes it easier to understand what's happening there. JavaScript's `||` operator is curiously-powerful (as I describe in [this blog post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) from many years back). It evaluates its left-hand operand and, if that value is *truthy*,¹ takes that value as its result; otherwise, it evaluates its right-hand operand and takes that value as its result. So `fn1() || fn2()` calls `fn1` and, if its return value is truthy, uses that value as its result (never calling `fn2`); if the return value from `fn1` is falsy, though, it calls `fn2()` and takes that value as its result (whether it's truthy or falsy).

The code finds the "solution" for 24 by starting with 1 and then repeatedly adding 5 to the `current` value or multiplying it by 3, via recursion. If it goes past the target value, it returns `null`. In the `||` expression I replaced with an `if`/`else` block, it adds 5 to the current value but if that takes us past the target it multiplies by 3 instead. (This is somewhat odd logic and won't find a "solution" for every value you give it.)

It takes quite a number of steps to find its "solution" (24 steps, in fact, which I *think* is just a bizarre coincidence). Here's what it does, using indentation to indicate the depth of recursion happening:

```
Checking 1 => 1
   Checking (1 + 5) => 6
     Checking ((1 + 5) + 5) => 11
       Checking (((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) => 16
         Checking ((((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) => 21
           Checking (((((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) => 26
           Checking (((((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) * 3) => 63
         Checking ((((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) * 3) => 48
       Checking (((1 + 5) + 5) * 3) => 33
     Checking ((1 + 5) * 3) => 18
       Checking (((1 + 5) * 3) + 5) => 23
         Checking ((((1 + 5) * 3) + 5) + 5) => 28
         Checking ((((1 + 5) * 3) + 5) * 3) => 69
       Checking (((1 + 5) * 3) * 3) => 54
   Checking (1 * 3) => 3
     Checking ((1 * 3) + 5) => 8
       Checking (((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) => 13
         Checking ((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) => 18
           Checking (((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) => 23
             Checking ((((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) => 28
             Checking ((((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) * 3) => 69
           Checking (((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) * 3) => 54
         Checking ((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) * 3) => 39
       Checking (((1 * 3) + 5) * 3) => 24
(((1 * 3) + 5) * 3)
```

For what it's worth, here's the code I used to get that output, but again, I recommend using the debugger, not `console.log` (though `console.log` can actually be helpful visualizing what's going on with recursion):

```js
function findSolution(target) {
    function find (current, history, depth) {
        console.log(`${"  ".repeat(depth)} Checking ${history} => ${current}`);
        if (current == target) {
            return history;
        } else if (current > target) {
            return null;
        } else {
            const plusFive = find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`, depth + 1);
            if (plusFive) {
                return plusFive;
            } else { // `plusFive` was probably `null`, could be `0`
                const timesThree = find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`, depth + 1);
                return timesThree;
            }
        }
    }
    return find(1, '1', 0);
}

console.log(findSolution(24));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

¹ "truthy" and "falsy" are terms used in JavaScript for values that, when used as booleans, convert to `true` or `false` respectively. There are only a few falsy values: `null`, `undefined`, `""`, `NaN`, `0`, and of course `false` (and on browsers, `document.all` for historic reasons). All other values are truthy.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your comment, I really didn't expect such a detailed answer!

where my questions arise that..... When current value gets past target number it uses 3 multiplication which is understandable. But even then, it's bigger than the target (like 26 to 63 in the process), so now why it's repeatedly decreasing the addition of 5 that was called earlier? 

maybe, as null is 'falsy' value it call backs somehow? I don't know.

Comment: @PallabBiswas - When `find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);` returns `null`, the `find` that called it *also* returns `null`. If that latter call was a `find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`);`, the `find` that called *it* will try again with `* 3`; but if it was another `find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);`, it also returns `null` to the `find` that called it. You can see that in the output shown above. The *first* call to `find` tries `+ 5` and there's lots of recursion, but it ends up going down the `* 3` path and always going past the target. So all of that recursion unwinds by ...

Comment: ...returning `null` until it gets all the way back to the first call to `find`, which then tries the `* 3` branch instead, which ends up finding a solution. You might try it with a pencil and paper, doing the work of `find` yourself. Sometimes that helps with the concept. Remember to indent a bit more on every line when you're starting a new recursive call, and then undo that when that call returns.

Comment: okay, why returning null reversing to the first call?

Comment: @PallabBiswas - Because the next line after ```const timesThree = find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);``` is `return timesThree;`.

Comment: why did you write (1 * 3) after (((1 + 5) * 3) * 3) in the 15th line of your checking solution section? Shouldn't it be (1 * 3) * 3)?

Comment: @PallabBiswas - **I** didn't write it, the code logging what actually happens wrote it (you can run it in the snippe that follows it, a I said above). After `Checking (((1 + 5) * 3) * 3) => 54`, all of the recursion started in the first call to `find` where it called `find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`, depth + 1);` (which is `(1 + 5)`) has unwound because it didn't find a solution and it's back to that first call to `find` again, which tries the `* 3` route starting with `(1 * 3) => 3`. Please step through the code in a debugger or work through it on paper (or both). :-)

Comment: Trust me, I've been working with this code all night long. written the process in paper though, that's where I got stuck...

Comment: @PallabBiswas - Sorry, my bad. :-)

Comment: it's ok. can you tell me how can I see every step that js executed in this code?

Comment: In your IDE or browser, go to the debugger (in browsers sometimes it's the "Source" panel in devtools). Right-click the `return find(1, '1');` statement and add a breakpoint. Execution of the code will stop at that breakpoint when it's reached. Now run the code (reload the page if doing this in a browser and the code already ran). When the breakpoint is hit, you'll have buttons to "step over" or "step into" each statement. There will also be a display of the "Call stack" somewhere. Step through the code (be sure to use "step into" on `find` calls), watch the call stack, and watch the vars. :-)